# Как исправить баг в запросе

Tags: php, mysql, sql

При получении значения из форму в $_POST записывается только одно слово из всех доступных. Например: В форме есть строка dish_name, куда выводится название блюда из таблицы. Блюдо имеет название "ТИГРОВЫЕ КРЕВЕТКИ АРАБЬЯТА". При нажатии на кнопку происходит отправка формы через POST и данные записываются в переменную $dish_name. Проблема заключается в том, что при отправке в $_POST записывается только первое слово из трех. Как это справить?

Входные данные: ТИГРОВЫЕ КРЕВЕТКИ АРАБЬЯТА

Результат: Array ( [dish_name] => ТИГРОВЫЕ )

Вот сам код:

````
<div class="dishes">
            <?php 
                $query_dishes = "SELECT *, k.category_name AS category FROM `блюда` AS b INNER JOIN `категория` AS k ON b.id_category = k.id"; 
                if(isset($_POST['category']))
                {
                    $id_category = $_POST['category'];
                    if($id_category != 0) {
                        $query_dishes = "SELECT *, k.category_name AS category FROM `блюда` AS b INNER JOIN `категория` AS k ON b.id_category = k.id WHERE id_category = $id_category";
                    }     
                }
                $result_select = mysqli_query($link, $query_dishes);
                while($dish = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_select)) { ?>
                    <div class='dish'>
                        <form class="dish_menu" action="zakaz.php" method="POST">
                <?php
                    echo " <img src='' alt=''>
                        <div class='product-bottom'>
                            <h3 name='dish_name'>".$dish['dish_name']."</h3> <input type='hidden' name='dish_name' value=".$dish['dish_name'].">
                            <p name='category'>".$dish['category']."</p><input type='hidden' name='category' value=".$dish['category'].">
                            <h4><input type='submit' value='Создать заказ' /><span class='item_price'> | Цена: ".$dish['count']." Руб.</span></h4> <input type='hidden' name='count' value=".$dish['count'].">
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div> "; } ?> 
            </div>


Вывод осуществляю через ``` print_r($_POST) ``` на другой странице
````

Comment: _Проблема заключается в том, что при отправке в $_POST записывается только первое слово из трех. Как это справить?_ - записывать все 3 слова... Как post получаете? Как можно хоть чем-то помочь ничего не видя?

Comment: Еще подозреваю что кто-то игнорирует кавычки для значений атрибутов. И получается в итоге `<input value=ТИГРОВЫЕ КРЕВЕТКИ АРАБЬЯТА name=dish_name />`.